# How to send a batch with emails in android?

Tags: android, email

I want to send several emails to different recipients, but the text of the letters may differ. And I also want to authorize the user and send mail on his behalf, by `Intent` and the built-in mail client app. And is there any way to do this with one button click, rather than calling up a new email window (activity) for each of these letters and forcing the user to confirms the sending of each letter?

And is there any way to not call the new e-mail window for each of these letters, so that the user confirms the sending of each letter, and do this at the touch of a button?

Maybe are there any third-party libraries or free mail services for this purpose?

Comment: using Intent and email apps, you can only send one email at a time. You may set multiple recipients, but the email text is the same for all. If you want to automate mailing, you will have to manually connect to mail server, and send emails manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [simple-java-mail](https://github.com/bbottema/simple-java-mail) to achieve that.

```
public static void SendMail(String recipientName,String recipientAddress,String subject,String message,File file,String myAdress,String password) throws IOException{


            System.out.println("File size "+file.length());

 Email email = new Email();
 email.setFromAddress(myAdress.split("@")[0], myAdress);
 email.addRecipient(recipientName, recipientAddress, Message.RecipientType.TO);
 email.setSubject(subject);
 email.setText(message);
 if(file!=null)
 email.addAttachment(file.getName(), 
FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file),"application/pdf");

 String host = myAdress.split("@")[1];
  new Mailer(
    new ServerConfig("smtp."+host, 587, myAdress, password),
    TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS,
    new ProxyConfig("socksproxy."+host, 1080, "proxy user", "proxy password")
 ).sendMail(email);


}
```

If your client is using Gmail, they have to allow third parties to send mail in their settings

Comment: How then to reassure a user to enter his email and password of mail box in my app? How to reassure that this is safely?..

Comment: With this approach you will ask the user to enter his email and password  of email box in own app, won't you? But, in my opinion, this is not trustworthy. Of course, I don't want to steal any credentials, but how to convice the user in this?

Comment: You can always save the credentials on a server

Comment: Do you mean "you can always save OWN credentials on a server"?
But I pointed in the post that "I also want to authorize the user and send mail on his behalf".

Comment: And if you meant "You can always save the USER'S credentials on a server", the problem isn't in saving, but in getting credentials.

Comment: Getting credentials isn't an issue. From my experience users don't usually mind. Just make sure that you mention that in your app's user agreement

Comment: If it is a GMail account, there is no need to ask the user for their password to send mail via Javamail. Authentication can be handled by using OAuth2, but you will need to obtain their auth token.